# Display Class Name instead of object in resultant Json Response

Tags: java, json, api, generics, jsonresponse

#### I have a generic class `Result<R>` and a class `JsonResponse`

```
public class JsonResponse {
    private boolean success;
    private Result result; //getter/settter
}
```

#### In my api, i am returning the json response for class ProductDeliveryCounter

```
Constraint constraint= getDeliveryCounter();
JsonResponse returnObject=new JsonResponse();
Result<Constraint> proMap=new Result<Constraint>(constraint);
        returnObject.setResult(proMap);
        
            returnObject.setSuccess(true);        return returnObject;
```

Output: [image: json result]

Query: Is there a way I can change the `object` in the image to `constraint`

Expected Output:  [image: edited json result]

Comment: can you post the code where you parse JsonResponse to the JSON format or send it to the client?

Comment: Could you please update your question and post whole method? also don't add images instead post the content in text only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `Jackson`, you can create a customized serializer to achieve this.

**Class CustomSerializer**

```
class CustomSerializer extends JsonSerializer<JsonResponse> {
@Override
public void serialize(JsonResponse value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
    jgen.writeStartObject();
    jgen.writeBooleanField("success", value.isSuccess());

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    JsonNode node = mapper.convertValue(value.getResult().getObject(), JsonNode.class);
    JsonNode rootNode = mapper.createObjectNode();
    ((ObjectNode) rootNode).set(value.getResult().getObject().getClass().getSimpleName(), node);
    jgen.writeObjectField("result", rootNode);

    jgen.writeEndObject();
}
```

}

And then add `@JsonSerialize(using = CustomSerializer.class)` to your class `JsonResponse` as follows.

```
@JsonSerialize(using = CustomSerializer.class)
public class JsonResponse {
    private boolean success;
    private Result<?> result;

    //general getters ans setters
}
```

**Code snippet for verification**

```
Constraint constraint = new Constraint();
constraint.setCutOffTime("2019-12-19T20:59:59.059");
constraint.setCurrentTime("2019-12-19T16:51:08.970");
constraint.setDeliveryPossible(false);

Result<Constraint> result = new Result<>(constraint);
JsonResponse returnObject = new JsonResponse();
returnObject.setSuccess(true);
returnObject.setResult(result);

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(returnObject));
```

**Console output**

> {"success":true,"result":{"Constraint":{"cutOffTime":"2019-12-19T20:59:59.059","currentTime":"2019-12-19T16:51:08.970","isDeliveryPossible":false}}}

Comment: Thanks, the solution worked. Is there any way to rename object as the name in annotation value over the class as well?

Comment: @Aarti Goel Hi, I think this should be another question. BTW, please accept my post as answer if it solved your problem, thanks!

Comment: @Aarti Goel Thank you! It sounds like that you don't want to rename it with class name? If yes, I think you should create a new question for this.